# Solving integral (by substitution?)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{b-x^2}}$ where b is a constant  ?

I know that $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \arcsin(x)$ , so I guess I have to substitute somehow clever. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Factor  $b$ out from the radicand. Then a substitution should come to mind.

Comment: $+ C {}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GFauxPas quite commonly we leave the trailing constant out. It doesn't harm any how.

Comment: @Vim Because the integral can also be evaluated $-\arccos x + C$, it does make a difference in this case

Comment: @GFauxPas Of course an integral can resolve to many, actually infinitely many functions, but one of them is enough. The difference between $\arcsin x$ and $-\arccos x$ doesn't really matter here. BTW, the $C$ is always left out by Maple when it calculates an indefinite integral.

Comment: The integral I **actually** have to solve is a definite one, so in my case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Use substitution $t=\sqrt{|b|}x$, then:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{b-x^2}}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{|b|}}{\sqrt{b-bt^2}}dt=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$

Comment: (forget this comment)

Comment: For $\sqrt{b-x^2}$ to make sense, we need $b\gt0$, so $|b|=b$.